# Pass function that receives params as param to class extension method

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to pass a function as parameter to a class extension method.

When doing

```
fun Router.handleJsonGet(path: String, method: () -> Any) {
    this.get(path).handler {
        it.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").end((gson.toJson(method())))
    }
}
```

I can easily wrap a function call inside a lambda and everything's working fine.

```
router.handleJsonGet("/business/list", { BusinessService.listBusinesses() })
```

Now I want to include a map of `GET` params and I'm getting stuck.

```
fun Router.handleJsonGet(path: String, method: (any:Any) -> Any) {
    this.get(path).handler {
        val map: MultiMap = it.request().params() ?: MultiMap.caseInsensitiveMultiMap()
        it.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").end((gson.toJson(method(map))))
    }
}
```

How do I make use of this method extension now? The wrap-with-lambda trick doesn't seem to work when the function requires a parameter.

I was expecting something like:

```
router.handleJsonGet("/business/list", BusinessService::listBusinesses)
```

with

```
object BusinessService {
    fun listBusinesses(any: Any) : List<Business> {
        // do something with any as MultiMap
        return Business.findAllBusinesss();
    } 
}
```

to work, but IntelliJ says Type Mismatch

Any idea how I should be passing a function that requires a parameter to a class extension method and how I should be calling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you tried to use (`BusinessService::listBusinesses`) is not yet supported for `object`s in Kotlin 1.0.4, it is only [planned for Kotlin 1.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/07/first-glimpse-of-kotlin-1-1-coroutines-type-aliases-and-more/) (Bound callable references).

Seems like you just need to use [lambda with argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax), either explicit or implicit `it`:

```
router.handleJsonGet("/business/list") { a -> BusinessService.listBusinesses(a) }
```

```
router.handleJsonGet("/business/list") { BusinessService.listBusinesses(it) }
```

Simplified example that demonstrates it:

```
object BusinessService {
    fun listBusinesses(any: Any): List<String> {
        return listOf("a", "b", "c");
    }
}

fun handleJsonGet(path: String, method: (Any) -> Any) {
    val map: Map<String, Int> = mapOf("a" to 1)
    method(map)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    handleJsonGet("1") { BusinessService.listBusinesses(it) }
}
```

Comment: that works, didn't know it would be that simple. Looking forward to the Kotlin 1.1 feature.

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
router.handleJsonGet("/business/list", {
   BusinessService.listBusinesses(anyParamHere)
})
```

Comment: `val map: MultiMap = it.request().params() ... ` is extracted inside the `fun Router.handleJsonGet(path: String, method: (any:Any) -> Any) {`, how do I get that map inside the Lambda so that I can pass it as a parameter as in your example?